# Copy non xml files from one directory to another using windows command

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file, command-line

I have a source folder where i have xml files and non xml files. I need to copy only non xml files from source to destination folder. 
I have written commands as below which does xml files copy from source to destination folder. But i need to non xml files. Kindly help.

```
@echo on
set SRCROOT=D:\input
set DESTNAME=D:\archive

echo Creating Directories...
if not exist %DESTNAME% md %DESTNAME%

echo Copying Files...
copy /Y %SRCROOT%\*.xml %DESTNAME%
```

**Update:** I tried as below and it worked. Looping through the directory and copying all non xml files:

```
@echo on
set SRCROOT=D:\input
set DESTNAME=D:\archive

echo Creating Directories...
if not exist %DESTNAME% md %DESTNAME%

@echo off
for %%i in (%SRCROOT%\*.*) do if not "%%~xi" == ".xml" copy /Y %%i %DESTNAME%
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) instead. It is available with the OS since Windows7. The `/xf` option allows you to exclude files, like `*.xml`:

```
robocopy %SRCROOT% %DESTNAME% * /xf *.xml
```

Otherwise xcopy has the `/exclude` option, but it takes a file. See [/exclude in xcopy just for a file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252176/exclude-in-xcopy-just-for-a-file-type).

Comment: It worked. But, my commands should be supported on older version of windows as well

Answer (score 1):

xcopy has an exclude option:

```
echo .xml >>c:\temp\exclude.txt
xcopy %SRCROOT%\*.* %DESTNAME% /exclude:c:\temp\exclude.txt
del c:\temp\exclude.txt
```