# "Can't read file" when trying to Exclude directory in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I've been stuck on this for awhile and could use some help.

I'm trying to copy a large folder from a mapped network drive (A:) onto my local PC. I also need to exclude a subdirectory on that drive path called "Images". My current code (*backup.bat*) is below:

```
cd %HOMEPATH%\Desktop\%mydate%
xcopy "A:\PROGRA~2\QuadTech" 121\ /e /EXCLUDE:"A:\PROGRA~2\QuadTech\INSPEC~1\Images\"
```

Error I keep getting:

[image]

I've tried shortening the path with "dir /x" and I am sure the path name is correct.  Also note that I need quotations as there are spaces in the PATH name.

Why am I getting errors when trying to Exclude this directory??

**ANSWERED**

I now have my Exclude statement point to my desktop where it reads a list of strings in a txt file.

```
xcopy "A:\PROGRA~2\QuadTech" 121\ /e /EXCLUDE:C:\Users\QuadTech\Desktop\excldelist.txt
```

Txt file contents:

```
\Images\
```

Comment: have you tried `/EXCLUDE:"A:\...\Images\*"` ?

Comment: @MikeNakis  I have.  Gives same error :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because the `/EXCLUDE` option does **not** specify files to exclude.

It specifies **files containing lists of files** to exclude.

More info by typing `xcopy /?`, though I am sure you know that.

(I know, I missed it too in the beginning; sometimes it is just a matter of having a second pair of eyes.)