# How to exclude a file type in XCOPY without passing a file?

Tags: windows, copy, copy-paste, xcopy

I have 5 txt files in my C drive, say

```
result_1.0.1.txt
result_1.0.1_tmp1.txt
result_1.0.1_tmp2.txt
result_1.0.1_tmp3.txt
result_1.0.1_tmp4.txt
```

At any point, there will be only 1 valid result txt file (in this case it is `result_1.0.1.txt`), and multiple tmp files. I want to copy only the `result_1.0.1.txt` using a generic XCOPY command. The version number in the file can be different each time. Earlier, only the `result_<version>.txt` file used to be present, so my XCOPY command looked like this

```
xcopy /Y "C:\*.txt" result.txt
```

To exclude the 'tmp' files, XCOPY requires a filename as the argument for /EXCLUDE parameter. Instead of that, is there a way to pass a wildcard argument? Something like this -

```
xcopy /Y "C:\*.txt" /EXCLUDE:"*tmp*" result.txt
```

Comment: You can use [`robocopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) which is a native Windows 10 tool/command and it supports wildcard characters (**\*** and **?**) for excluding files using `/xf <FileName>` option. See `/x*` and `/xf` in [File selection options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy#file-selection-options) of Robocopy. I can add an answer with an example for your case if you're interesting using Robocopy.

Answer (score 3):

Per the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4252213/1174966), you need to create a new file with the patterns you want to exclude. Using a wildcard is not possible.

So you can create a file `exclusions.txt` (in a different directory) with the contents:

```
_tmp
```

That's all.

Then you can run

```
xcopy /Y "C:\*.txt" /EXCLUDE:exclusions.txt result.txt
```

You can also generate `exclusions.txt` dynamically as is done in [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/743092).

**Or**, if your file names will always be in the exact format you're showing, you could skip using `EXCLUDE` entirely and instead use something like:

```
xcopy /Y "C:\*.?.txt" result.txt
```

The `?` is a single character wildcard, so this will match any file ending in `.1.txt`, `.2.txt`, etc., which your `tmp` files  don't have. You could even get more specific and use `*.?.?.txt` or `result*.?.?.txt`.

Comment: I feel using the approach based on regex is more reliable **until** the pattern of file-name remains the same. It can help tackle the problem that might arise just in case the file being read for things to exclude gets corrupted.